# Automatically show the foreignkey's other fields in django

Tags: django

I am trying to show the field(s) related to its foreignkey on html. Let's see I have two models as shown below:

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Model_Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False, blank = False, unique = True)
    item_unit = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null = False, blank = False) # can be kilogram, pound, ounce, etc

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item_name

class Model_Weight(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Model_Item, to_field = "item_name")
    item_weight = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item
```

On Model_Item model, each item can have its own unit, and there can be many items. Then we will choose the item on the second model (Model_Weight), and insert the value of the weight that is according to its unit.

How can we show the corresponding "item_unit" in html, such that when we have selected the "item_name", its unit will show/hover somewhere in the webpage which enables us to put the correct weight value?

These are the rest of the codes:

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Model_Weight

class Form_Weight(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model_Weight
        fields = ["item", "item_weight"]
```

## views.py

```
from .models import Model_Weight
from .forms import Form_Weight
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class View_Weight_CV(CreateView):
    form_class = Form_Weight

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit = False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(View_Weight_CV, self).form_valid(form)
```

## html

```
<form method = "POST" action = "" enctype = "multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.item}}
    <!-- {{ form.model_item.item_unit }} Automatically shows this field once an item has been selected --> 
    {{ form.item_weight}}
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick solution is to change `__unicode__` method definition of `Model_Item` model

```
def __unicode__(self):
    # add item_unit with name
    return self.item_name + " (" + self. item_unit + ")"
```

Now in your HTML template, the item dropdown will be shown like

```
{{ form.item }} #--> Bread (Kg)
                #--> Rice (Kg)
                #--> ...
```

If you want to show unit under item dropdown, keep above settings as it is and add below javascript code at bottom of your HTML template

```
$(document).on('change', '#id_item', function(){

   // you can also make ajax request from here
   // I am using selected item text for now 

   var item = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
   // item = 'Bread (Kg)'
   var result = item.match(/\((.*)\)/);
   // matched text inside round brackets 
   // result[1] = Kg
   $( "#id_item" ).after( "<p>"+result[1]+"</p>" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that but the item name can be too long (>100 chars) thus makes it hard to read.

Comment: So there are 2 ways you can achieve it, either you make an ajax get request to get item_unit of that particular item or you can add some javascript to get unit inside from string that we rendered with unit and show it under dropdown

Comment: Hey your method works! I did a slight change on your Javascript code, and now it runs nicely. Thanks.